# find the departments with the most employees in Xquery

Tags: xquery

I am trying to find the departments with the most employees (and its number of employees) in the  following xml document:

```
  <organization>
    <departements>
        <dept id="d1">
            <name>accounting</name>
        </dept>
        <dept id="d2">
            <name>marketing</name>
        </dept>
        <dept id="d3">
            <name>production</name>
        </dept>
    </departements>
    <employees>
        <emp id="e1">
            <name>...</name>
            <activities>
                <activity ref="d1"/>
            </activities>
        </emp>
        <emp id="e2">
            <name>...</name>
            <activities>
                <activity ref="d2"/>
                <activity ref="d3"/>
            </activities>
        </emp>
        <emp id="e3">
            <name>...</name>
            <activities>
                <activity ref="d3"/>
            </activities>
        </emp>
        <emp id="e4">
            <name>...</name>
            <activities>
                <activity ref="d2"/>
            </activities>
        </emp>
    </employees>
</organization>
```

Here is what i have tried:

```
(for $dept in doc('emp_dept.xml') //dept
let $nbr := count(doc('emp_dept.xml')//activity[@ref = $dept/@id])
order by $nbr descending
return $dept ) [1]
```

The above query returns the following output:

```
<dept id="d2">
    <name>marketing</name>
</dept>
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
<dept id="d2">
    <name>marketing</name>
    <employees>2</employees>
</dept>
<dept id="d3">
    <name>production</name>
    <employees>2</employees>
</dept>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* create the `dept` elements you want to output, determine the highest number of employees, and then output the ones that match that max count.

I'm sure there is a more efficient way, but this is what first came to mind.

```
let $doc := doc('emp_dept.xml')
let $newDept := for $dept in $doc//dept 
    return 
        <dept>{$dept/@*,$dept/*,
        <employees>{count($doc//emp[activities/activity/@ref=$dept/@id])}</employees>
        }</dept>
let $maxEmployees := max($newDept/employees)
return
    $newDept[employees=$maxEmployees]
```